# Using :after with :last-child in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two phone numbers marked up as a list. I need to prefix the first with "Foo: " and the second with "Bar: ". I can achieve "Foo: " but not "Bar: ". Based on the below code, how can I achieve "Bar: "?

```css
#top_bar .phone .icon-phone:after {
  content: 'Foo:';
}
#top_bar .phone:last-child .icon-phone:after {
  content: 'Bar:';
}
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
  <ul class="contact_details">
    <li class="phone">
      <i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:00001">00001</a>
    </li>
    <li class="phone">
      <i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:00002">00002</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mail">
      <i class="icon-mail "></i><a href="mailto:foo@bar.com ">foo@bar.com</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use :nth-of-type(2) selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `:nth-child(n)`?  It is very helpful to solve this kind of stuff:

```css
#top_bar .phone:nth-child(1) .icon-phone:after{
  content: 'Foo:';
}
#top_bar .phone:nth-child(2) .icon-phone:after {
  content: 'Bar:';
}
```

```html
<div id="top_bar">
  <ul class="contact_details">
    <li class="phone">
      <i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:00001">00001</a>
    </li>
    <li class="phone">
      <i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:00002">00002</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mail">
      <i class="icon-mail "></i><a href="mailto:foo@bar.com ">foo@bar.com</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.phone:nth-child(1):before  { content: 'Foo:'; font-style: italic; }
.phone:nth-child(2):before  { content: 'Bar:'; font-style: italic; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/dbvyx9xn/2/)

Comment: A slight (and probably less efficient) variation to the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the distinction. My answer selection was chronological.